# REST resource with field from join

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I have a resource Task that is exposed via /task
I also have a resource TaskExecutions which is exposed by /taskexecutions

Both resources are entities in my model and I must list the Tasks but recover a field from the TaskExecution via join on a specific field to get the max execution time from the task

**My question is**:
What is the best design for a rest API in this case?
Should I just add the field on the response or create another resource url that exposes this "composed" resource?